# Solution to avoid a record from being inserted in Salesforce

Tags: triggers, salesforce, lookup, apex

I am in need of stopping a record from being inserted when a certain condition is met. I made this change in beforeInsert of my trigger with the help of addError().
I have an issue with this solution: [apex addError - remove default error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55635709/apex-adderror-remove-default-error-message).
I want to remove this default error message and keep only my customized message. And I want to make this bold and bit bigger too. I am now convinced that these things are not possible with addError().

Is there any alternative solution to this? I mean, to stop this record from being inserted?

My object in concern is ObjectA. And ObjectA has a lookup to ObjectB. This ObjectB field in ObjectA has to be unique. No two ObjectA records can contain the lookup to same ObjectB field. That's when I need to stop this insertion.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> bold and bit bigger too

Possible only if you have custom UI (Visualforce / Aura Component / Lightning Web Component...). I wouldn't spend too much time on this. Focus on getting your logic right and making sure it runs also via API (so not only manual insert but also Data Loader is protected for example).

if `addError` doesn't do what you need then consider adding a helper text(18) field. Mark it unique and use a `before insert,before update` trigger (or workflow) to populate it with value from that lookup.

Uniqueness should be handled by database. Are you really ready to write that "before insert" perfectly? What about update? What about undelete (restore from recycle bin?) What if I'll want to load 2 identical records at same time? That trigger starts to look bit more complex. What if user is not allowed to see the record with which the clash should be detected (sharing rules etc... I mean your scenario sounds like the uniqueness should be "global" but you need really good reason to write "without sharing" code in the trigger handler).

It's all certainly possible but it's so much easier to just make it with an unique field and call it a day. And tell business to deal with the not necessarily friendly error message.